# How to slice a string where start and end are defined by two different substrings?

Tags: python, string, list, string-matching

So I have a list of strings such as this:

```
list_strings=["YYYYATGMBMSSBAHHH","CCCCUINDAKSLLL","HHHHKJSHAKJJKKKK","ERRREEJK","XZXZOOOOYYYFFFFAKSXXX","RRRRRKJUUUUNNNNNGYRRRRRR","HHHHSDAFF"]
```

And I have two lists of patterns to be searched for in each string:

```
forward_patterns=['ATG', 'KJ', 'OOOO','UI']
reverse_patterns=['GY', 'AKS','BA','JK']
```

I want, for each string in `list_strings`, to be sliced from the position of one `forward_patterns` pattern until the position of one `reverse_patterns` pattern (both, start and end patterns should be removed as well). The string should be sliced only once for each list of patterns, considering only the first occurence that is found. It's irrelevant which of the patterns inside either of the lists of patterns is found and used for the slicing

My output in this case would be this:

```
list_strings=["MBMSS","ND","SHATGKJ","untrimmed","YYYFFFF","UUUUNNNNN","untrimmed"]
```

I have tried with these for loops but unfortunately it isn't trimming any of them:

```
for i in range(len(list_strings)):
    for pf in forward_patterns:
        beg=list_strings[i].find(pf)
        for pr in reverse_patterns:
            end=list_strings[i].rfind(pr)
            if(beg !=-1 and end !=-1):
                list_strings[i]=list_strings[i][beg+len(pf):end]
            else:
                list_strings[i]="untrimmed"
```

Basically I'm getting a list of all "untrimmed" but I don't know why:

```
list_strings=["untrimmed","untrimmed","untrimmed","untrimmed","untrimmed","untrimmed","untrimmed"]
```

What could be wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: why "AAAMBMSSBA" becomes "MBMSS"? there is no forward pattern "AAA"

Comment: sorry I'll correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the last update:

```
res_list = []

for s in list_strings:
    upatedString = s
    for f in forward_patterns:
        if f in upatedString:
            upatedString = upatedString[upatedString.index(f)+len(f):]
            break
    for r in reverse_patterns:
        if r in upatedString:
            upatedString = upatedString[:upatedString.index(r)]
            break
    
    if len(upatedString) == len(s):
        res_list.append("Untrimmed")
    else:
        res_list.append(upatedString)

res_list
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my input for a little clarity, it was a bit misleading before.
Because most of the times, the reverse pattern is not at the end of the string, but in the middle. The same situation is for the forward patterns as well. The patterns are usually somewhere in the middle of the strings, hence why I didn't use the "startswith" and "endswith". Again sorry because the previous input was misleading

Comment: @Ok, so then what you need is to replace patterns independently of where they are in the string? then why not to put them all in a single list?

Comment: Basically I want, for each string, to find any of the forward patterns and cut everything that is to the left of it (including the pattern itself). The same for the reverse patterns: find one of them in reverse order, and cut everything to the right of it (including the pattern itself). They are in two lists because what I want is to keep only the subset of the string that is between one of the forward and one of the reverse patterns.

Comment: @tadeufontes ok, I believe I got your point, give a try to the new update

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit confusing. I dont get why 'ERRREEJK' is untrimmed, even if 'JK' is in the reverse pattern oO.
Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
list_strings=["YYYYATGMBMSSBAHHH","CCCCUINDAKSLLL","HHHHKJSHAKJJKKKK","ERRREEJK","XZXZOOOOYYYFFFFAKSXXX","RRRRRKJUUUUNNNNNGYRRRRRR","HHHHSDAFF"]
forward_patterns=['ATG', 'KJ', 'OOOO','UI']
reverse_patterns=['GY', 'AKS','BA','JK']
 
new_strings = []
for string in list_strings:
    for pattern in forward_patterns:
        _temp = string.split(pattern,1)
        if len(_temp) == 2:
            _temp = _temp[1]
            break
        else:
            _temp = _temp[0]
    for pattern in reverse_patterns:
        _temp = _temp.rsplit(pattern,1)[0]
        if len(_temp) == 2:
            break
    if string == _temp:
        new_strings.append('untrimmed')
    else:
        new_strings.append(_temp)
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. the reason for that is that in order for a string to be trimmed, it has to contain at least one forward pattern and one reverse pattern